# Python: Textfile reading in parts

Tags: python, file-io

I have a read-in problem with python. I'm new at that business...

The part of the program looks like that:

```
for line in f.readlines():
   if ... :
   print(line)
```

Is it possible, not only to print that line, but also the next line? (even if it does not fulfill the if...)

I tried it with:

```
for k,line in enumerate(f.readlines())
```

But I don't know how to print a line by its number (k)

Is there any easy solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print lines 1, 2; then 2, 3; then 3, 4 or do you want to just print in groups of 2 (i.e. first 1, 2; then 3, 4; then 5, 6.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to read the whole file into memory to do this:

```
prev = None
for line in f:
    if prev is None:
        prev = line
    else:
        print prev + line
        prev = line
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the list of lines in a variable:

```
lines = f.readlines()
for k, line in enumerate(lines):
    # line         - current line
    # lines[k + 1] - next line
```

Note that you should check whether `k < len(lines) - 1` before accessing `lines[k + 1]`.

The above approach, as well as your original approach, requires the entire file to be loaded to memory upfront. If you want to save some memory, you can make your loop read lines from the files incrementally:

```
def iter_lines(f):
    """Iterate over lines in f, providing the current and next line."""
    it = iter(f)
    this_line = None
    for this_line in it:
        break  # only get first line
    else:
        return # no lines in the file
    for next_line in it:
        yield this_line, next_line
        this_line = next_line
    yield this_line, None

for line, next_line in iter_lines(f):
    # line: current line
    # next_line: next line, or None if at the last line
```

Comment: You are great. 
Now everything works perfectly.

Thanks a lot